# Java Generics- Can I create a list dynamically based on variable type

Tags: java, generics

Is there any way by which we can create specific instance of generic type at runtime?

For example.

```
Cacheable instance = getCacheable(someInput);
```

getCacheble method will return me the instance of Cacheable. So it can be any class implementing Cacheable.for e.g. Customer,Product etc.Now I want to create a list of specific type returned by getCacheable as below.Is that possible? If yes how to do that?

```
List<? extends Cacheable> cacheList = new ArrayList<>();
```

I want to create `ArrayList<Product> or ArrayList<Customer>` based on the instance returned by getCacheable method.

Comment: Due to erasure this is somewhat irrational because a List doesn't have a type at run time. Generics are for compile time checks. So the real answer depends on your actual use case. Why do you want compile time checks and how? At run time you can put anything in any list and generics just serve as a gatekeeper.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this:

```
Cacheable instance = getCacheable(someInput);
List<? extends Cacheable> l = new ArrayList<>();
l = Collections.checkedList(l, instance.getClass());
```

Because of type erasure, all information accessible at compile time is lost at runtime.
The [`checkedList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#checkedList%28java.util.List,%20java.lang.Class%29) method will ensure that  your list will receive only instances of the class of `instance` variable.

**UPDATE:**
You can do this also:

```
public static <T extends Cacheable> MyOwnCustomGeneric<T> createMyOwnCustomGeneric(Class<T> type) {
    return new MyOwnCustomGeneric<T>();
}

// ...
IMyOwnCustomGeneric foo = createMyOwnCustomGeneric(instance.getClass());
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.The prob is I am not actually using List, its my own custom generic class.I took List as an example to simplify the prob statement.

Comment: @Jai Is you own custom generic class is a `Collection` (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html) ? If so, you can use `checkedCollection` instead of `checkedList`.

Comment: No Alex.Its not collection. I wanted to avoid the instance of check here, but I think its not possible.

Comment: @Jai I have added an alternative if you want to avoid instance of check.

Comment: @Alex, i have actually proposed this in my answer before your update when i noticed that you have mentioned the built-in approach :)

Comment: Note that the parameter `type` is not used and can be removed from `createMyOwnCustomGeneric`.

Answer (score 2):

Use generic helper function:

```
public static <T extends Cacheable>ArrayList<T> createList(Class<T> claz)
{
       return new ArrayList<>();
}

ArrayList<? extends Cacheable>alist = createList(instance.getClass());
```

Comment: Note that the parameter `claz` is not used and can be removed.

Comment: @PaulBellora, isn't it required to infer the type from the instance's own type. I understand that as `alist` has the type `ArrayList<? extends Cacheable>`  it is not needed

Comment: Type inference is something that happens at compile time. If it fails type arguments can be manually specified with e.g. `MyClass.<Product>createList()`. But considering that generic types have been erased at runtime, what the OP is asking for doesn't make sense. `createList(instance.getClass())` can be reduced to `new ArrayList<Cacheable>()` because at runtime it's all just `ArrayList`.

Comment: @PaulBellora, that is not just that, with `ArrayList<? extends Cacheble>`: we can't actually add an element to the list. Not even it will allow us to add element of type `Cacheble` itself. So yes, it wasn't making sense to me either :)

Comment: The diamond operator isn't supported by Java 6 though. (Agreed 6 is a long time ago)

Answer (score 0):

```
if (instance instanceof Product) { 
   // create ArrayList<Product>; 
} else { 
   // create ArrayList<Customer>;
}
```

This is not really general and dynamic though.

Comment: But I like Alex's answer more.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to do it is by switching on the type of `instance` but there isn't much you can do with it:

```
List<? extends Cacheable> cacheList = null;
if (instance instanceof Product)
  cacheList = new ArrayList<Product>();
// etc
```

But what can you do with this list? You cannot add anything to it. Maybe you add items to it while creating it, but that is probably not the use case since it is a *cache* list.

If you need to add items to it later, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20531765/18573) is the right approach.

If you are not going add items later, it does not matter if the type is `List<Cacheable>` or `List<? extends Cacheable>`